# element.classList.addClass is not a function when testing Animate.css

Tags: javascript, css-animations, internet-explorer-11, animate.css

I've downloaded the `Animate.min.css` from the github [repo](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css). 
I can see an initial animation after page load.

```
<h1 class="animated bounce delay-2s">Example</h1>
```

but, if I click on a button:

```
<button onclick = "myclick()">Animate</button>
```

the javascript function

```
function myclick() {
  const element =  document.querySelector('.my-modern');
  element.classList.addClass('animated', 'bounceOutLeft');
}
```

throws an exception

```
test_animate.html:14 Uncaught TypeError: element.classList.addClass is not a function
    at myclick (test_animate.html:14)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test_animate.html:9)
```

I've also tried adding jquery with no success

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

but I've no idea what I'm supposed to do to fix this issue.

I'd expect to see the following paragraph being animated.

```
<p name="par_test" class="my-modern">Test this</p>
```

### Edit (found that the issue is IE11 specific)

I copied the `addClass` from debugging the [Animate homepage](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) after seeing this line

```
  function testAnim(x) {
    $('#animationSandbox').removeClass().addClass(x + ' animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
      $(this).removeClass();
    });
  };
```

As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483052/element-classlist-addclass-is-not-a-function-when-testing-animate-css#comment103297606_58483052)
I've corrected it into

```
element.classList.add('animated', 'bounceOutLeft');
```

and now the exception has disappeared, but I still can't see the expected animation **only on IE11**. In Chrome it is all ok.
I've posted this as an [issue on github](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/987).

Comment: `element.classList.addClass` correct, it's `element.classList.add` - as per *[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods)*

Comment: well ... that's probably something to do with your CSS - which you haven't shown

Answer (score 1):

`Element.classList.addClass` is not a function, as you've discovered already. `Element.classList.add` is, and while IE11 supports it, it does not support supplying multiple arguments to it as you're doing.

There is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Polyfill) available on MDN which you could use, or you could use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I've found that the following code is working for both Chrome and IE11 as expected.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="animated bounce delay-2s">Example</h1>
  <h2 name="par_test" id ="par_id" class="my-modern">Test this</h2>
  <button onclick = "myclick()">Animate</button>
</body>
<script>
function myclick() {
  $('.my-modern').addClass('bounceOutLeft animated');
}
</script>
</html>
```

It looks like using the jQuery API [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) (instead of the vanilla JavaScript `classList.add`) solved my issue.

Actually I derived it from reverse engineering the homepage and not by following the readme of the repository.

### Edit

As already pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483052/element-classlist-addclass-is-not-a-function-when-testing-animate-css/58485416#58485416), the root cause of the issue for IE11 is that

> it does not support supplying multiple arguments to `Element.classList.add`

so, besides adding the polyfill or using jQuery, one could have simply done:

```
element.classList.add('bounceInDown');
element.classList.add('animated');
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.